# How to add node and subnode with values to Firebase in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning how to build android app and i would appreciate help in this matter. I would like to know how to add node and then subnode of that node with values to Firebase. I'm using Android Studio and i have saved data with push(), but in this case i don't need generated key, key already exists. I need to add grocery_list_key_1 then product_key_x (there is more of them) and atributes for product_key_x with values.

[image: screenshot of firebase database]

This keys are entered manually on screenshot for demonstration. Firebase generated string for them because they are primary keys in another table. I know this is nosql database but need some mechanism to simulate it.

In method saveGL_withProducts i have entered GroceryList in node grocerylists with atributes and values and get back generated key which one i want to add as child in grocerylistproducts node with list of products.

```
public void saveGL_withProducts(GroceryListsModel groceryListsModel, List<GroceryListProductsModel> groceryListProductsModels){

    if (firebaseDatabase == null)
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(GROCERYLISTSNODE);
    DatabaseReference pushRef = ref.push();
    pushRef.setValue(groceryListsModel);
    String generated_GL_key = pushRef.getKey();


    if(!isNullOrBlank(generated_GL_key)){


        //TO DO ADDING IN GROCERYLISTPRODUCTS NODE



    }
    else{
        //TO DO

    }



}
```

Appreciate any suggestion. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write) for common examples. The `push` method will insert a new node with a unique key, whereas the `setValue` method can be used to insert data to a specific node.

The node where data is to be inserted can specified in the following manner:

```
User user = new User(name, email);
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
```

Here, the `User` class is a POJO that provides structure to the data. It should also be possible to use a `Map` that describes the mapping instead of a class.

In your case, the code would be something like:

```
ref.child("grocery_list_key_1").child("product_key_1").setValue(data);
```

Assuming `ref` points to the 'grocerylistproducts' node. As you can see, you will need to know the names of all intermediate nodes in advance for this to work.

Further, the `setValue` method overwrites any existing node information. Thus, you should use suitable update methods as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data), if only certain fields are to be modified.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works! In this case i'm only adding new data so nothing is overwritten.